# Difference of image and imagery in writing paper

Tags: remote-sensing

Sorry I'm not sure if I should post this question here, or in the "English language usage" site. Because this is a question typically related to the remote sensing paper.

I'm writing a paper about remote sensing, and I don't know when should I use "image" and "imagery". I've read many remote sensing-related papers, but I haven't discerned how they distinguish between these two terms. For example, in this [paper](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=biuzU-AAAAAJ&sortby=pubdate&citation_for_view=biuzU-AAAAAJ:YB4bud6kWLwC) , it seems that the "imagery" is used for "satellite imagery", and one real image is "image", right?

Comment: That sounds like a fair rule. I would say that imagery is georeferenced but an image is not; an image can be geolocated but that just shows where the image was taken. Though I have heard the term satelite image to refer to just one scene (singular).

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you!

Comment: I agree, a satellite image is a singular object. The term "imagery" can refer to a collection of images. Perhaps the term is also used to distinguish imaging sensors from spectroscopy and other remote sensing techniques? For example, many sensors used in astronomy & Earth Observation are spectroradiometers; they are not imaging sensors. Similarly, conventional radar is used for ranging, whereas synthetic aperture radar can produce an image. TLDR: Perhaps the term "imagery" also indicates the use of an imaging sensor?